# Search Engine Results - Not Ranking

Tags: html, seo, search-engine

I am somewhat embarassed to ask this as I feel I should know. How do i get all of my web pages to show hierarchically under the main page of my website on search engine results like the image below:
[image: All Results listed hierarchically]

instead of the "usual" single result that appears for most web pages?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know how to use Google Sitelinks

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en&safe=strict

Answer (score 0):

It's shows and selected by Google automatically most of the pages are most important pages of your site because the visitors from Google interested to visit theme but you can just select it If you want to show or not to show It in your site result search from Google webmaster / site link